# How to check if a string contains certain characters using an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to check if a string contains illegal character and I was wondering if there is a way to do it through an array because I have an array character that are allowed. This is in PHP

The array just in case you want to see it:

```
$MsgAry1 = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
           "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
           "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d",
           "e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
           "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x",
           "y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
           "9","0",".",",","'","?","!"," ","_","-");
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `str_split` and `in_array` functions to do this, as thus:

```
$MsgAry1 = array("A","B","C"); //Add your actual array here
$testCase = "Hello, World!";
$testCase_arr = str_split($testCase);

foreach($testCase as $test)
{
    if(!in_array($test, $MsgAry1))
    {
        echo "Error! Invalid Character!";
        break(); //Or exit();, as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: so this will show invalid characters like a pound sign?

Comment: Yes. It will show an error message for any character not contained in the array of valid characters you provide, i.e. `$MsgAry1` in this case.

Comment: Didn't you mean to `foreach($testCase_arr)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-iterative method, which should perform faster than the existing answers that loop.

```
function containsIllegalChars($testString) {
    static $MsgAry1 = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
           "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
           "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d",
           "e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
           "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x",
           "y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
           "9","0",".",",","'","?","!"," ","_","-");
    $foundCount = 0;
    str_replace($MsgAry1, '', $testString, $foundCount);
    return $foundCount > 0;
}
```

You can make it even more efficient with your specific set of letters by removing all the uppercase letters, and using str_ireplace.

```
function containsIllegalChars($testString) {
    static $MsgAry1 = array("a","b","c","d",
           "e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
           "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x",
           "y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
           "9","0",".",",","'","?","!"," ","_","-");
    $foundCount = 0;
    str_ireplace($MsgAry1, '', $testString, $foundCount);
    return $foundCount > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this, `str_split` splits the string into characters then you can check each one with `in_array`:

```
$MsgAry1 = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
           "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
           "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d",
           "e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
           "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x",
           "y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
           "9","0",".",",","'","?","!"," ","_","-");

$string = "Hello";

foreach (str_split($string) as $char) {
        if (in_array($char, $MsgAry1)) {
            echo "Char: ".$char." -> OK";
        } else {
            echo "Char: ".$char." -> KO";
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$resultarray = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $MsgAry1);
print_r ($resultarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop ...but if you did use a loop, then you'd better use an early `return`/`break` so that you aren't doing unnecessary iterations after you've found a disqualifying character.

In a project of my own, I'd prefer to store the regex expression instead of an array of characters -- it's just more concise and direct.

If you must an array of characters, you can avoid the explode and loop by trimming all of the safe characters and check if any characters remain after trimming.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Hr4M6))

```
$MsgAry1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
           "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
           "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d",
           "e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
           "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x",
           "y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
           "9","0",".",",","'","?","!"," ","_","-"];

$strings = [
    'test',
    '1234',
    'w0ws3r!',
    '##tag##',
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,'?! _-"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo "$string match: " . var_export(!preg_match("~[^\w.,'?! -]~", $string), true) . "\n";
    echo "$string ltrim:  " . var_export(!strlen(ltrim($string, implode($MsgAry1))), true) . "\n";
    echo "$string after trim: \"" . ltrim($string, "A..Za..z0..9.,'?! _-") .  "\"\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
test match: true
test ltrim:  true
test after trim: ""
---
1234 match: true
1234 ltrim:  true
1234 after trim: ""
---
w0ws3r! match: true
w0ws3r! ltrim:  true
w0ws3r! after trim: ""
---
##tag## match: false
##tag## ltrim:  false
##tag## after trim: "##tag##"
---
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,'?! _- match: true
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,'?! _- ltrim:  true
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,'?! _- after trim: ""
---
```

`!strlen(ltrim($string, "A..Za..z0..9.,'?! _-"))` demonstrates that you can use multiple character ranges in the "character mask" parameter so long as you use `..` to indicate each range.  I believe this is the most concise, non-regex technique.  Again, if the trimmed string has length, then at least one bad character was found.

No matter which technique you prefer, I strongly discourage iterated calls of `in_array()` -- the performance cost will balloon as the length of the input string increases.