# PHP Cut At specific character "@"

Tags: php, get

I have this code at the moment in php the GET Receives words from a variable and the vast majority starts with a "@" then I add a "substr" to omit the first character which is "@" but there is a time when I get words without the @, is there some way to omit only the @? I would very much appreciate the help thank you very much!!

```
$soe = $_GET["option"];
$so = substr($soe, 1);
```

Comment: Can't you just use an `if` statement to check if the word begins with `@`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trim the `@` character from the left.  If it's there it's removed, if not then it stays the same:

```
$so = ltrim($soe, '@');
```

If you run in to a situation where you want to remove multiple characters, then you can specify them or a range:

```
$so = ltrim($soe, '@#');
// or
$so = ltrim($soe, '0..9'); // all numbers 0 through 9
```

You can do the same with `rtrim` for the right or `trim` for both ends.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I can ask you something extra... sorry D:, but I have an array with some words that if they match the word they receive from the GET they print a message, but sometimes it doesn't work because it doesn't match the capitals, is there any way to ignore the capitals and minicules? :( and sorry I'm very new to php

$channel = array(
      "AnyAny" => $prefix. "",

Comment: Ask that as a new question with code and what you want to match.

Comment: I never knew about the `0..9` range feature.

Comment: You can even use multiple ranges in the character mask. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322208/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the string begins with `@`

```
$so = $soe[0] == "@" ? substr($soe, 1) : $soe;
```

Comment: You can use `strcasecmp()` to perform case-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: or you can make the array all lowercase, and convert the user input to lowercase with `strtolower()`